# Initial Value Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this math problem:$$\frac{dP}{dt}=0.01P(1-0.001P); P_0=50$$

This is a differential equation, but I have no idea how to solve it.

$$\frac{1}{0.01P(1-0.001P)}dP=dt$$

$$\frac{1}{0.01P-0.00001P^2}dP=dt$$

$$\int{\frac{1}{0.01P-0.00001P^2}dP}=\int{dt}$$
$$ln\left | 0.01P-0.00001P^2\right |=t?$$

Comment: Look for the method of separation of variables. In the meantime you forgot about $P^2$

Comment: That's what I am supposed to use, but what does P_0=50 mean?

Comment: I guess it is $P|_{t=0}=P_0$.

Comment: $P_0 = 50$ gives the initial value of $P$. (The value at time $t = 0$ )

Comment: You are on the right track but you've integrated wrong on the left-hand side.

Comment: @amcalde, did I? is it the ln?

Comment: $\int \frac{dx}{a x-b x^2} = \frac{\log (x)}{a}-\frac{\log (a-b x)}{a}$

Comment: Your last integral is not equal your final answer. $u = 0.01P - 0.00001P^2 \implies du = 0.01 - 0.00002P\,dP.$ Recall that $\int \dfrac {f'}{f} \,dP = \ln|f|$.

Comment: @KFC also note that $$\int dt = t+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Go with partial fraction decomposition. $$\int \frac{1}{0.01P(1-0.001P)}dP =\int \frac{1}{0.01P}+\frac{1}{10(1-0.001P)}dP \\ = \int \left(\frac{1}{0.01}\right)\frac{1}{P}+\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)\frac{1}{10-0.01P}dP  \\ = \int\frac{100}{P}+\frac{100}{1000-P}dP \\ = 100\int \frac{1}{P}+\frac{1}{1000-P}dP $$ The rest should be pretty easy to integrate. You'll get an answer in terms of the natural logarithm.